# Calculating integrals of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions

Tags: integration

> Calculate the following integrals:
>
> A) $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3-x^2}} \, dx$
>
> B) $\int \frac{2x}{cos^2 (5x)} \, dx$
>
> C) $\int sin(3x+5).sh(x) \, dx$

Well, for A), I tried naming $u=\sqrt{3-x^2}$ but I have problems with $x^2$. I tried calling $u=3-x^2$ but then my problem is $du$ because of the $x$.

In B), I know that I can take the 2 out, and then call $5x=u$, but what can I do with $\frac{1}{cos^2 (u)}$?

In C) I tried naming $t=3x+5$ so that I got $dt=3dx$, and then I have to compute $\frac{1}{3}\int sin(t).sh(\frac{t-5}{3}) \, dt$, and I thought that I could use integration by parts, but independently on what part I call $u$ and $dv$, the function that I have to integrate is ugly, and also I have to integrate hyperbolic functions, which are "cyclical" when integrating or differentiating.

Comment: You identify that these should be using trig substitutions.  Try using one in A.  In B rewrite as  $\int 2x\sec^2 5x \ dx$ and use integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

For the B) and C) use integration by parts, the fastest way I used to solve them  is the D.I. Method. There are many videos about it, helps a lot.

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{B)}& D.& I.\\ \hline
 +& x& \sec^2(5x)\\ \hline
 -& 1& \dfrac{1}{5}\tan(5x)\\ \hline
 +& 0& -\dfrac{1}{25}\ln(\cos(5x))\\ \hline
\end{array} \hspace{2.5cm}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{C)}& D.& I.\\ \hline
 +& \sin(3x+5)& \sinh x\\ \hline
 -& 3\cos(3x+5)& \cosh x\\ \hline
 +& -9\sin(3x+5)& \sinh x\\ \hline
 \end{array}\\$$
$B)\quad 2\int x\sec^2(5x)\ dx= \dfrac{2}{5}x\tan(5x)+\dfrac{1}{25}\ln\left|\cos(5x)\right|+C \\ C)\quad R=\int\sin(3x+5)\sinh x\ dx=\sin(3x+5)\cosh x-3\cos(3x+5)\sinh x-9R\\ \qquad R=\dfrac{1}{10}\Big[\sin(3x+5)\cosh x-3\cos(3x+5)\sinh x\Big]+C \hspace{2cm} \forall\ x\in \mathbb{R} $

Another way to solve C) is using the complex definitions of $\sin x=\frac{e^{-ix}-e^{ix}}{2i}$, (replacing $x$ by $3x+5$) and $\sinh x=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints

A) For the first integral you can consider $x = \sqrt{3}\sin(u)$, then $dx = \sqrt{3}\cos(u)$.

Thus,

$$\int \frac{3\sin^{2}(u) \sqrt{3}\cos(u)}{\sqrt{3 - 3\sin^{2}(u)}}dx = \int\frac{3\sin^{2}(u)\sqrt{3}\cos(u)}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1 - \sin^{2}(u)}}dx = \int \frac{3\sin^{2}(u)\sqrt{3}\cos(u)}{\sqrt{3}\cos(u)}dx = $$
$\int 3\sin^{2}(u)dx$

B)$$\int \frac{2x}{\cos^{2}(5x)}dx = \int x\sec^{2}(5x) dx$$
Now, you can use integration by parts in $\int x\sec^{2}(5x)dx$

C) Try use integration by parts

$$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$$

$u = \sin(3x + 5) \Rightarrow du = 3\cos(3x + 5)dx$ and

$dv = \sinh(x)dx \Rightarrow v = \cosh(x)$

Comment: MathJax hints:  for multicharacter square roots enclose them in braces.  The square root sign will extend long enough, so \sqrt{1000} gives $\sqrt{1000}$.  If you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$